# 503 slow down in emr with s3-cp-dist

Tags: amazon-s3, hdfs, emr

I' m tried to copy a partitioned parquet file from my "local" hdfs (Amazon elastic map reduce). and I have got always the same error.

when I execute
```

```
s3-dist-cp --src /myparquet --dest s3a://mys3path.com/mydest
```

```

I get this

```

```
17/07/10 20:42:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
17/07/10 20:43:06 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
17/07/10 20:43:17 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 5%
17/07/10 20:43:18 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 6%
17/07/10 20:43:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 7%
17/07/10 20:43:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 9%
17/07/10 20:43:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 11%
17/07/10 20:43:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 14%
17/07/10 20:43:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 16%
17/07/10 20:43:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 18%
17/07/10 20:43:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 21%
17/07/10 20:43:26 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 23%
17/07/10 20:43:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 25%
17/07/10 20:43:28 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 27%
17/07/10 20:43:29 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 29%
17/07/10 20:43:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 31%
17/07/10 20:43:31 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 33%
17/07/10 20:43:32 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 35%
17/07/10 20:43:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 38%
17/07/10 20:43:34 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 40%
17/07/10 20:43:35 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 42%
17/07/10 20:43:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 44%
17/07/10 20:43:37 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 46%
17/07/10 20:43:38 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 48%
17/07/10 20:43:39 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 50%
17/07/10 20:43:40 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 52%
17/07/10 20:43:41 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 55%
17/07/10 20:43:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 57%
17/07/10 20:43:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 59%
17/07/10 20:43:44 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 61%
17/07/10 20:43:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 63%
17/07/10 20:43:46 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 65%
17/07/10 20:43:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 67%
17/07/10 20:44:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 68%
17/07/10 20:44:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1499714528879_0003_r_000122_0, Status : FAILED
Error: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Slow Down (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 503; Error Code: 503 Slow Down; Request ID: 52A8AF1F5C2D0A04
```

```

My cluster configuration is
```

```
--instance-groups \
InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=r3.8xlarge,BidPrice=5.0 \
 InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=20,InstanceType=r3.8xlarge,BidPrice=5.0
```

```

there is some way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is AWS throttling your requests and the Apache S3A client not being up to recognizing them and reacting to them properly (waiting and retrying), instead, at least of aug 1, 2017. [Future readers: check [HADOOP-14381](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-14381) to see if it is now fixed).

If you are using `s3-dist-cp` then that's the amazon libs you are working with. Try switching the dest url to `s3://mys3path.com/mydest` to make sure its Amazon's own S3 client, not the apache s3a one, which is being used to write the data.

Comment: don't know why this got voted down. Whoever did it has never had to field support calls related to multi-terabyte distcp job being throttled because they were all working with the same shard and the cleanup at the end of the put [tries to do too much work](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-15209)